# Showing that any total nonincreasing functions on $\mathbb{N}$ must be effectively calculable

Tags: computability, monotone-functions

So I stumbled into the aforementioned exercise in Enderton's book on computability. It is presented in the first chapter -- "effectively calculable" is defined informally and is akin to say, partial recursive.

Now, I'm not sure about this one. For instance, let $\bar{H} = \{ x | \text{ machine } x\text{ does not halt on input }x\}$. Now let $f$ be the following function: $f(0) = 10^{100}$, $f(x+1) = \text{the greatest } y\in\bar{H}\text{ s.t. } y\leq f(x)$. Now, $f$ is clearly well-defined and nonincreasing, though not effectively calculable.

Similarly, there is another exercise next which asks the same about periodic functions, and I think one could then think of a similar incalculable function there.

In any case, seeing as we are in an introductory chapter, I think a hand-wavy, appealing-to-intuition explanation is expected, though I can't really think of any. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it help that $f$ is eventually constant :-)

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, but, we are not guaranteed to know when that happens, I guess? And even if we knew when, how does this imply that we can calculate it for instance at inputs where it isn't constant?

Comment: Well, you wanted a hand-waving explanation :-)

Comment: Hah, correct. I expected one that wouldn't break down if we got technical though. Do you think there isn't any such explanation?

Comment: I am not sure.  You seem to have a valid objection. Try to add some tags to attract attention of people in related fields.

Comment: Any suggestions of tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl;dr: There is a difference between a function $f$ which is *known* - that is, effectively calculable, and for some index $e$ we can *prove* that $\varphi_e=f$ - and one which is merely *effectively calculable* - that is, $f=\varphi_e$ for some $e$, but maybe we can't prove *which* $e$ has this property.

---

Any eventually constant function *is* effectively calculable, even if we don't know what Turing machine does the job. There is no rule saying that we have to *prove* that $\varphi_e=f$ for some $e$, just that it has to be the case that $\varphi_e=f$ for some $e$.

Specifically, if $f$ is any eventually constant function, $f$ is determined by a finite amount of information:

- The finite string $\sigma$ which is $f\upharpoonright n$, where $f(m)=f(k)$ for all $m, k\ge n$.
- The eventual value $v$ of $f$: $f(n+1)$, that is.

This is a block of finitely much information, and there's a Turing machine which, on input $i$, behaves as follows:

- Checks if $i\ge n$.
- If yes: output $v$.
- If no: output the $i$th value of $\sigma$.

This is a perfectly reasonable Turing machine! Now, of course, for any finite string $\tau$ and any number $u$, there's a similar Turing machine which behaves with $\tau$ instead of $\sigma$ and $u$ instead of $v$, and *that* machine obviously won't do what we want it to in general, and there may be no obvious way of distinguishing the "right" machine from the "wrong" machine, but that's fine: all that's required is for a right machine to *exist*.

---

A perhaps easier example to think about: show that every constant function is effectively calculable. Note that there are some weird constant functions, like $f(x)=0$ if the Riemann Hypothesis is true and $f(x)=1$ otherwise. Once you understand why every constant function is computable, you'll understand why every eventually constant function is, too.

Comment: Oh, yes, yes. The crucial point here being that we don't need to pin down the $e$ such that $\phi_{e} =f$, just assert that it exists -- indeed some machine computes the $f$ I proposed in the OP, for example, we just don't know its index. Interesting your mention of "being determined by a finite amount of information". That is related to one way I like to think about the usual uncomputable functions, say Kolmogorov complexity -- one proof that I like of its uncomputability "hints" that a machine that computed it would have to have a "nonstandard" (greater than any other) number of states.

Comment: Just to overemphasize the key point: the definition of 'computable function'  is "there exists a program to compute the function". The definition has an existential quantifier in it, and to prove a sentence with an existential quantifier we only have to show that there is some value that works - we don't need to know the exact value.  In other words, we treat the existential quantifier here exactly the same as any other existential quantifier in mathematics.